# Can I use Telerik ASP.NET MVC extensions on real projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, licensing, telerik-mvc

Can I use Telerik ASP.NET MVC extensions on commercial projects for free? (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/)

Are there any limitations?

Comment: is it free for Commercial use? http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/

Comment: @MVCSpider It's licensed under GPL2. So, [yes](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#DoesTheGPLAllowMoney) you can use it royalty free in commercial applications as long as you follow the license restrictions.

Comment: @hawkke but when we download the Telerik extension from the site they have different license agreement. just click on download and read the license agreement.

Comment: @MVCSpider You are correct, they include a separate license file - it's the same license as what is included when you download the source after you purchase a license. But it is for sure dual licensed under Telerik's commercial license and GPL 2.0 (or [GPL 3.0](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/licensing.html) according to their online documentation...it may be worth contacting Telerik support to get them to clarify since different websites conflict on the specific version of GPL). Their open source license is GPL, so you can use their extensions under those terms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use them for free. You need to buy the license. You can first use the trial for free though.

http://www.telerik.com/purchase/individual-kendoui-mvc.aspx

Comment: But this is kendoui! I am talking about asp.net mvc extensions!

Comment: Both seems to be the same : http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/extensions.aspx

Comment: Looks like Kendo is a successor of "telerik asp.net mvc extensions" hmm...

Answer (score 5):

Telerik's MVC extensions are open-source under GPL, so yes you can use them and sell your product as long as you follow the restrictions of the license. The codeplex site says the latest version available is Q32011, so they aren't the most up-to-date.

[Telerik MVC Extensions on Codeplex](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/)

If you need the more current version (which is now deprecated by Kendo and I believe support ends Q32013) or support then you need to purchase a license.